# Error regarding xml file in android. No resource found that matches the given name @text

Tags: java, android, xml

This is my about.xml file which is the layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/about_text"
android:id="@+id/abouttextview"></TextView>
</ScrollView>
```

This is the strings.xml file which contains the the matter to display when about button is clicked

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World, Hangman!</string>
    <string name="app_name">Android Hangman</string>
    <string name="about_text">Hangman is the classic game that has
    players
    trying to guess their opponent's mystery word first--and
    before
    getting hanged. For every wrong letter chosen, a bit more
    of the hangman is exposed.</string>
    <string name="about_title">About Android Hangman</string>
 </resources>
```

i am getting error at android:text=@strings/about_Text line of about.xml that no resource found that matches the given name

Comment: i have checked all your code its just working fine. just replace the special characters and put \ before your apostrophe . clean your project and save.

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys- still getting da same error

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `\` symbol before special characters in `strings.xml`.

**opponent\'s**

```
      ^^
```

**string.xml**

```
<string name="about_text">Hangman is the classic game that has
    players
    trying to guess their opponent\'s mystery word first--and
    before
    getting hanged. For every wrong letter chosen, a bit more
    of the hangman is exposed.</string>
```

**about.xml**

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/abouttextview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/about_text" >
        </TextView>
    </ScrollView>
```

Its working in my case.

Comment: no dude.... its not getting solved.. cleaned da project. Actually wen i click about button.. it should show the text in strings.xml file in inflated menu

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I saw was a missing `\` before the `'` apostrophe at the word `opponent's` in the string resource.

Change it to this:

```
<string name="about_text">Hangman is the classic game that has
players
trying to guess their opponent\'s mystery word first--and
before
getting hanged. For every wrong letter chosen, a bit more
of the hangman is exposed.</string>
```

Comment: @Hardik: Actually, as it turns out, I hadn't missed it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1)Save all your work

2)Select the project and Right click, then Refresh

3)Select Project>Clean

It supposed to work

Note: Put '/' before any special char (Non-alpha numerical characters)